# Regular expression \Q and \E

Tags: regex

I want to whitelist a url such as https://blatest-0124658.cat.mat.import.com

However the number in between which in the above case is 0124658 keeps changing.

I want to try something with `\\Q` and `\\E`:

```
"\\Qhttps://blatest-<value>.cat.mat.import.com\\E"
```

I am following this page here https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html
and can see maybe `\w` will help?

i tried this below:

```
"\\Qhttps://blatest-\\w.cat.mat.import.com\\E"
```

not sure if i have got the syntax properly or if it even is right -- can someone guide please?

Comment: Double backslash makes the backslash literal, not an escape sequence. You might need to double it when using a string literal in a programming language, but that's not part of the regex syntax.

Comment: And a number of languages have "raw" strings so you can avoid having to escape backslashes.

Comment: i have tried the suggestion but i get this error: parsing error: invalid character '.' in string escape code"

Comment: It should be: `\bhttps://blatest-\\w+\\.cat\\.mat\\.import\\.com\b`